# Unit test with Dependency Injection using struture map

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am new to MVC and IoC and other related concepts.

I have to write unit test cases for an old project. It uses Structure Map for Dependecy Injection. Third party dlls that I use expose some interfaces. Now I have to write unit test cases for methods in the controller class.

The constructor of controller looks like this:

```
HomeController(IClientData clientdata)
{
    _clientdata = clientdata;
}
//The clientdata was initialized
```

In my test case, how do I initialize the controller class and interface like `IClientData`? Passing `IClientData clientdata` to constructor says: `passing type as var`.

How do I initialize/mock the data in `IClientData`? I don't know how the interface is implemented in the dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using implementations of interfaces in a unit test, you should use a mocking framework like [Moq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.available(v=vs.110).aspx) and you can set up those interfaces to return the default values that satisfy your testing requirements. In this case, you would create a Mock to set up the values you would **expect to see in this particular expected use case** and then pass that into your controller.

```
var mockClientData = new Mock<IClientData>();

mockClientData.SetupGet(data => data.MyProperty).Returns(3);
// mockClientData.Object.MyProperty now returns 3

mockClientData.Setup(data => data.MyMethod()).Returns(42);
// mockClientData.Object.MyMethod() now returns 42
// any other setup that you need done goes here

var controller = new HomeController(mockClientData.Object);

// the rest of your test as normal
```

It's important to note that you shouldn't rely on an implementation of a dependency in a unit test, because then you are no longer testing a unit of code - you are writing an integration test.

Comment: If I use moq, I've to set data myself, right? But the thing is: My controller starts with a set of clientdata that is initialized via IClientdata passed in constructor. I want to use same initial data. Don't want to setup it myself. How can I do that?

Comment: I will of course mock data passed to the concerned function that I need to test.

Comment: I'm slightly confused here. `My controller starts with a set of clientdata that is initialized via IClientdata passed in constructor.` You are meant to pass the mock into the constructor which is setup to return the data you expect to see. That data is then used *in place* of an `IClientData` you would pass in during production

Comment: If you are doing a unit test, you really should be setting up all the data yourself so you remove any external dependencies or "what-ifs". A unit test should be a black box that is executed in a controlled environment which you have complete control over - this includes setting up any variables and having control over them.

Comment: Okay. I'll try to explain again. There is a set of default data passed to the constructor via IClientdata. I guess that is done by di(structure map here). I want to use same data to initialize constructor and then unit test my function by mocking data as I want.

Comment: In which case you would set up IClientData's fields/methods to return values that are identical to the default IClientData instance setup via StructureMap. I can't tell you where your StructureMap configuration is in your project - only you know that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59095/discussion-between-maxsteel-and-dan-pantry).

Comment: @Maxsteel, I support Dan's answer - see my additions in the new lengthy answer

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to mimic the real world in a unit test. A unit test should verify that a certain unit (here, the controller) behaves in the specified way if it is given a set of preconditions.

From your comments on Dan's answer I gather that you seem not to know exactly what data the controller gets in real life. You can only write a unit test if you know exactly what the preconditions must look like and how the controller should behave given those conditions. So you have two options:

- Try and find out the real data by inspecting any processes that are involved in building the `IClientData`. This requires you to inspect the source code of the dlls.
- Analyze the source code of the controller. Where does it access the `IClientData`? What checks does it perform? Based on that you can make conclusions of what is required and how the input affects the controller's behavior. You can then write a unit test that documents that.

The second option implies that you create tests that document the "is" state, even though that state might theoretically deviate from what was originally intended. You probably don't have an other option since you write the tests in retrospect. But at least the names and contents of your unit tests will make those implicit things very explicit. You could take your tests to the developers and ask them: "This is how the controller seems to behave like. Is it correct?"

Whatever option you choose, you must end up with the knowledge of what preconditions and expected behavior are. Once you have that you are able to write this down by using `Moq` or any other way to write stubs or mocks as in Dan's answer. For each test case you write one or several test methods. Each method only makes one logical assertion. Therefore each test method should also only require a very limited set of initializations of your `IClientData` mock.

tl;dr?

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy explanation. I appreciate it. The thing is, I can mock interface and use it to initialize controller but the interface is huge and mocking it will require lot of effort. For eg: there are multiple data members that are class. I cannot possibly mock everything. SO I wanted to use the default implementation as it is instead and only mock params of the function that I need to test.

Comment: Every field in the huge interface is necessary *for the test you're currently writing*?

Comment: Yes. One is necessary, rest are dependent on it. It's a complex, huge project.

Comment: @DanielMann Any idea how do I simply use same, default implementations.

Comment: As I mentioned in the chat to you, only mock the parts you need for the method you are testing *right now*. Each method (and each use case) should have it's own unit test, with it's own different mocking. If the method and use case you are testing now requires `Model.Foo` and `Model.Bar` but not `Model.Baz`, you only need to mock `Model.Foo` and `Model.Bar` - you can ignore `Model.Baz` as it's never used; you do **not** need to mock properties/methods/whatevers that are not being used in the current unit under test.

Comment: If you end up mocking members that are not being used in the current unit under test but are mocking them because part of the execution path uses them, it is a sign you need to refactor as your code is doing more than one thing and violating SRP - or that you should perhaps move some of the dependencies from `IClientData` to the method's arguments instead.

Comment: Sorry for triple post - it may be worth you showing us a method that needs testing so we can point out how you would mock the `IClientData` so you can get an idea of how it would work

Comment: @Maxsteel: You might have some misunderstandings about what unit testing is. One unit test method should only test one particular small thing, e.g. one method call on the controller. Moq will create a default implementation for the whole interface. Only the parts whose behavior is relevant for the method under test need to be explicitly mocked. If a single method in the controller uses a lot of calls on your interface this might be a case for you to tell your employer that the legacy code is not unit-testable.