# Unable to get Default Constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, constructor, default-constructor

I an getting the below issue when running the Unit Test project.

> Unable to get Default Constructor For class ********

```
[TestClass]
public class PersonRegistration
{
    private ILoggingService _loggingService;
    private IUserManager _userManager;
    public PersonRegistration(IUserManager userManager, ILoggingService loggingService)
    {
        this._userManager = userManager;
        this._loggingService = loggingService;
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        RegisterBindingModel model = new RegisterBindingModel();
        AccountController ac = new AccountController(_userManager, _loggingService);
        model.UserName = "test123@gmail.com";
        var result = ac.Register(model);
        Assert.AreEqual("User Registered Successfully", result);
    }
```

How to fix that. Some answers says that to use a parameter less constructor. But here I need params.

RegisterBindingModel()

```
public class RegisterBindingModel
{
    public RegisterBindingModel();
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Issue [image]

Comment: Counstructor for what class? Can you show constructors of `RegisterBindingModel`?

Comment: just add a parameter less constructor as well. The test frameworks requires it i believe.

Comment: Are you sure you need constructor with parameters for test fixture? I believe you can get all dependencies via mocks, of course if you doing unit testing

Comment: So, how is the test runner meant to know how to conjure an `IUserManager` and an `ILoggingService` instance from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a mocking framework like [Moq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.available(v=vs.110).aspx).

Example:

```
[TestClass]
public class PersonRegistration
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        RegisterBindingModel model = new RegisterBindingModel();

        var mockService = new Mock<ILoggingService>();//Mock
   //Do something as per your requirement 
   //var reg= new List<RegisterBindingModel >(); // provide some sample list 
    //mockService .Setup(r => r.GetAll=()).Return(reg);

        var mockManager = new Mock<IUserManager>();//Mock

    //Do something as per your requirement 
    //var user= new List<User>(); // provide some sample list 
    //mockManager .Setup(r => r.GetAll=()).Return(user);

        AccountController ac = new AccountController(mockManager.Object, mockService.Object);
        model.UserName = "test123@gmail.com";
        var result = ac.Register(model);
        Assert.AreEqual("User Registered Successfully", result);
    }
}
```

You can get help form [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240983/unit-test-with-dependency-injection-using-struture-map) and [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/unit-test-using-mock-object-in-dependency-injection/) link.

Comment: Your first link "Moq" goes to a Socket.Available Property page. I think that's incorrect

Answer (score 3):

I've just tested this in my unit tests.

Add

```
public PersonRegistration()
{
}
```

And it should run fine.

There is no need for constructors on your unit test classses. If you are using a mocking framework like Moq then I use a factory to return the dependent moqs for the classes I'm testing.

```
 public ILoggingService ReturnMockLoggingService()
 {
       var mockService = new Mock<ILoggingService>();
       return mockService.Object;
 }
```

Then in the test fixture.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    RegisterBindingModel model = new RegisterBindingModel();

    var logService = MockFactory.ReturnMockLoggingService();
    var userService = MockFactory.ReturnMockUserService();
    AccountController ac = new AccountController(userService, logService);

    model.UserName = "test123@gmail.com";
    var result = ac.Register(model);
    Assert.AreEqual("User Registered Successfully", result);
}
```

if you're not using mocks then simply instance the user and log service in the test or create a SetUp.

```
[ClassInitialize]
public void SetUp()
{
    _loggingService = new LoggingService();
    _userManager = new UserManager();
}
```

Hope that helps.